# How to insert/get entities from the google cloud Data Store (python)

Tags: database, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to make a python program that uses the google cloud data store in python and i am having some trouble with the DataStore input\output system. this is my first time working with google cloud, and i am also somewhat new to python.
I am trying to build a very simple database, with only 1 type of entity model- 'Command', which has 2 variables- 'name' which i want to be the key, and 'value'. all the entities will have one parent, because the google cloud guide said this will put all the entities in the same entity group, which helps sort them? (i am not sure about this, so explanation will be nice)

```
class Command(ndb.Model):
    value = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    # no 'name' variable, since it's the key.

def parent_key():
    return ndb.Key(Command, DEFAULT_PARENT_NAME)
```

when the user uses a 'set' command, the code will either insert a new entity with the given name and value, or if the name exists already, it will change the existing value to the given value.
(assume 'variable_name' is the name and 'variable_value' is the value)
this is the code for the 'set' command:

```
variable_name = self.request.get('name')
variable_value = self.request.get('value')
newcommand = Command(id=variable_name, value=int(variable_value), parent=parent_key()) # create a new command model
newcommand.put()
```

this inserts a new command, but doesn't check if it is already in the datastore.
i want the 'get' command to extract the value of an existing name in the database (or return an error, if it doesn't exist), given the name (in a string)
in the online manual i found how to extract stuff from the database given a key, but here i dont have a key, i have a string.

I don't know how to complete the 'set' and 'get' commands and would appreciate some help with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using AppEngine standard with your Python implementation?

Comment: I am using the Google Cloud SDK Shell to run the cloud stuff

Comment: You cannot create ndb models via the cloud SDK this has to be done via a deployment ... you mention in your description that you have a python program, this is why I ask about details of your deployment

Comment: The way i understood it, i write in the shell "dev_appserver.py app.yaml", which runs a local version of the program, and with it active, i use "http://localhost:8080/Whatever_I_Want_To_Write" to simulate access to it. this is according to their manual here : "https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server". i know how to deploy the program to the cloud, but doing it every single time i make a change is troublesome. will it not work the way i just described?

Comment: i would advise you run through this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/storing-data-datastore